# Sharing multiple ggplot legend symbols with one label

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, legend, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a stacked barplot for one response over time (Year) across 3 different sites that I've separated into different facets (facet_wrap). I would like different colours per facet, and I thought the easiest way of achieving this would be to create a new variable ('Col_Var'), but keeping the facet per site. This gives me almost exactly what I'm after.

[image]

But I would like a **simpler legend** whereby all of the darker colours (i.e., 3 boxes) are placed next to the 'Type A' label, and the 3 lighter colour boxes are places next to 'Type B' (my labels are ideally much longer than this so the legend becomes very chaotic). In  other words, **can I place multiple boxes / symbols next to 1 label in a ggplot legend?** Some example code below, any help or advice much appreciated, many thanks.

```
Plot_df <- data.frame(Site = rep(c("Site A","Site B","Site C"),each =10), 
                      Type = rep(c("Type A","Type B"),times =15), 
                      Year = rep(rep(seq(2010,2014,1),each=2),times=3),
                      Value = rnorm(30, mean=50, sd=10))
Plot_df$Col_Var <- as.factor(paste(Plot_df$Site,Plot_df$Type))

Stacked_Plot_Colours <- "#027E5D" "#89EFC7" "#6F2D01" "#F5773A" "#3A3663" "#8F8ACD"

 Stacked_Plot <- ggplot(Plot_df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(Year), y = Value, fill = Col_Var),position = "stack",stat = 
"identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ Site,ncol=1) +  scale_fill_manual(values=Stacked_Plot_Colours)+
  theme(legend.position = "top",legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
Stacked_Plot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your legend one option would be to replace the first two labels per row by an empty string and do some cleaning for the last label:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Plot_df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.factor(Year), y = Value, fill = Col_Var),
    position = "stack", stat =
      "identity"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~Site, ncol = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    labels = \(x) {
      x[!seq_along(x) %in% 5:6] <- ""
      gsub("^Site\\s.*?\\s", "", x)
    },
    values = Stacked_Plot_Colours
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")
  )
```

[image]

**UPDATE** If you want to put the legend in one row you could reorder the categories or keys using the `breaks` argument. However, doing so also requires to account for the reordered breaks when replacing the "undesired" labels by the empty string:

```
scale_fill_manual(
  breaks = \(x) {
    x[c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)]
  },
  labels = \(x) {
    x[!seq_along(x) %% 3 == 0] <- ""
    gsub("^Site\\s.*?\\s", "", x)
  },
  values = Stacked_Plot_Colours,
  guide = guide_legend(nrow = 1)
)
```

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant thanks! Any idea how to change the legend so its one 1 row? I tried using  '+guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=1))' but it doesn't work as the colours are then jumbled up.

Comment: See my update to have only one row.